# How to access $.widget.prototype in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

On web page, $.widget.prototype does not contain any functions like _trigger, _setOption.

I am new to JQuery and want to know why and how to see this private functions on web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.Widget is the base class of $.widget and _trigger is defined in $.Widget. 
And in JQuery UI widget.js, $.Widget.prototype is assigned to the JQuery UI widget object prototype created by $.widget.

so $.widget.prototype._trigger does not exist, but _trigger exists in prototype of real UI widget.